# How to perform "nslookup host server"

Tags: c#, api, nslookup

My `C#` service needs to periodically poll `nslookup host server`. Currently it spawns a `Process` that executes batch script. Due to performance reason I'm considering to do this check using some `API`. But the problem is, that using, for example, `System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses` I can only emulate `nslookup host` check, but not `nslookup host server` (without seconds param).

I've looked at bunch of similar SO questions, but none of them seem to solve my issue.

Are there any way to perform `nslookup host server` in `C#` without using some heavy third-patry library?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem was solved!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682016(VS.85).aspx

See "***Great Example here***" section

```
[DllImport("dnsapi", EntryPoint="DnsQuery_W", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError=true, ExactSpelling=true)]
private static extern int DnsQuery([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.VBByRefStr)]ref string pszName, QueryTypes wType, QueryOptions options, int aipServers, ref IntPtr ppQueryResults, int pReserved);
[DllImport("dnsapi", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
private static extern void DnsRecordListFree(IntPtr pRecordList, int FreeType);

...
```

Comment: Unfortunately the "Great Example here" section is no longer present on the msdn url you posted. Know of any other ways to accomplish 'nslookup host server'?

Comment: @KlomDark look here for more implementation + example: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/dnsapi.DnsQuery

Answer (score 1):

I looked into this a while back.  It is not possible in the standard class libraries, so you are going to have to use an external component to do this properly.

There are a number of free and paid choices available to you.  My implementation was based around [a posting on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/dnslookupdotnet.aspx), which worked quite well.  [DNS Client Library for .NET](http://www.simpledns.com/dns-client-lib.aspx) (also mentioned by kprobst) was released after I finished mine, or I would've used this one initially.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do this using the framework directly because I've never needed to use a DNS server different than the one specified in the local machine configuration. But you might want to give [this](http://www.simpledns.com/dns-client-lib.aspx) library a try. I've never used it but as far as I can tell it will allow you to specify a DNS server to use in resolving the host name you pass.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 7 there is now [`Dns.GetHostEntryAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.dns.gethostentryasync) method but unfortunately it doesn't have an argument for `server` in its overloads even though the implementation for Windows can potentially support it.