# find domain name server with ASP or ASP.net

Tags: dns, nameservers

I'm trying to find a function that I will send her a domain name and show will return me the name servers of this domain name (NS1,NS2).

Someone know where can I find that?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this as reference, there isn´t any problem to use it on asp.net if your are using c#

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/DougBell/NSLookUpDB00112052005013753AM/NSLookUpDB001.aspx

Edit: refer to this stack question too:
[How to perform "nslookup host server"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468348/how-to-perform-nslookup-host-server)

Good Luck!